# Does drinking hot water reduces paunch?

Tags: water, stomach, benefits

Does drinking hot water instead of cool water reduces paunch. In what way hot water helping to decrease the fat in the body ?

Comment: If that's true, how come the world is full of people who have hot water and paunches?

Comment: drinking hot water may reduce cholesterol in the body. That is why am asking whether this will help to reduce paunch or not..